# What is right way to use global package with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, global, enzyme

I am using [global](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global) package to enable using some methods of enzyme  in my tests files without importing:

```
import { configure, shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
   .....
global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
```

So I am able to write

```
const component = shallow(<Input {...props} />);
```

in my test file without import of `shallow` method

But typescript doesn't know about this and I get error:
 `[ts] Cannot find name 'shallow'.`

How can I tell to typescript about these globals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `declare` is used for. Add the following line to the top of your test file:

`declare const shallow:any; // Maybe more specific type information if you have`;

Instead of using declare, you could also typecast the window object like this:

```
const component = (window as any).shallow(<Input {...props} />);
```

or like this:

```
const component = (<any> window).shallow(<Input {...props} />);
```

But keep in mind, exposing functions as global objects is not a good practice. Especially when you have two functions of the same name, as one will override the other.

Comment: Is there way to add this line in one file for all my tests file?

Comment: Afaik there is no way to do that. You could however typecast the window object instead of using that line. I'll update my answer on that.